# Natbib produce errors when being included

Tags: natbib

**Problem:**

Following the recommendations to use the Natbib according to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management, I continue to receive errors when I try to follow the guidelines.

**The error:**

```
natbib.sty (line 351)
LaTex error: Unknown option 'options' for package 'natbib'. (\newcommand)
```

Code for **thesis.tex**:

```
%Default style using S5 paper
%\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisSU_A4}
%Use this instead if you need A4 paper.
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisSU}

%: Macro file for Latex
% Macros help you summarize frequently repeated Latex commands.
% Here, they are placed in an external file /Latex/Macros/MacroFile1.tex
% An macro that you may use frequently is the figuremacro
\include{Latex/Macros/MacroFile1}

\usepackage[options]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{emptypage}

% Change how references are included (see the natbib package).
\setcitestyle{square,numbers}
```

...

```
%: ----------------------- ´Bibliography ------------------------

% The section below defines how references are listed and formatted.

%\begin{multicols}{2} % \begin{multicols}{ # columns}[ header text][ space] %uncomment to have 2 columns
\begin{scriptsize} % tiny(5) < scriptsize(7) < footnotesize(8) < small (9)

%Default style file. Change according to you preferences.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

% Changes the header from Bibliography to References
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

% File containing all references in BibTex format
\bibliography{thesis} 

\end{scriptsize}
```

Code for **thesis.cls**:

```
%-------------------------- identification ---------------------
%\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisSU}[2011/09/23 PhD thesis class]

%:-------------------------- book style -----------------------

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{book} 

%:-------------------------- packages for fancy things -----------------------
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Default font for dissertations is Times.
%\usepackage{fourier} % If mathematics don't display well using Times, then use Fourier.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption,tabulary}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} % for improved inclusion of graphics
\usepackage{epstopdf} % converts eps figures to pdf
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % for improved layout of figure captions with extra margin, smaller font than text
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for better header layout
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english,swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{enumerate} % enumerated list for List of Papers
%\usepackage[sort,compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{multicol} % for pages with multiple text columns, e.g. References
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt} % space between columns; default 10pt quite narrow
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % correct page numbers for bib in TOC, nottoc suppresses an entry for TOC itself
%\usepackage{nextpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calligra}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}

\renewcommand\boldsymbol[1]{\pmb{#1}}

 \DeclareFixedFont{\timesEightteen}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{\seriesdefault}{\shapedefault}{17\p@}

% Removing the "Chapter n" text an replacing it by a single number.
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace{0\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      % Skipping the "Chapter n" text 
      \if@mainmatter
        \baselineskip=20pt\rightskip 2cm plus 3cm\LARGE\thechapter.\hspace{0.5em}%Chapterpoint added.
      \fi
    \fi
    \LARGE #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 74\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{0\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 74\p@
  }}


%:-------------------------- Glossary/Abbrev./Symbols -----------------------

\usepackage{nomencl} % load nomencl extension; include in TOC
%\nomrefpage % to include page numbers after abbrevations
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % make abbreviations bold
\makenomenclature % used to be \makeglossary
\newcommand{\g}{\footnote{For all abbreviations see the glossary on page \pageref{nom}.}} % type "\g" to refer to glossary

% used to be for sorting into categories:
%\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
%  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
%   \item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}] }{%             A - Roman
%    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
%     \item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%             G - Greek
%      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
%        \item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{%              R - Superscripts
%          \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
%           \item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{{%             S - Subscripts
%       \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
%        \item[\textbf{Other Symbols}]}{{%    X - Other Symbols
%       \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Z}}{%
%        \item[\textbf{Acronyms}]}%              Z - Acronyms
%                       {{}}}}}}}}}}


%:-------------------------- PDF/PS setup -----------------------

%if you use a macTeX 2008 or later, use the ifpdf package
\usepackage{ifpdf} 


%-->
%--> Google.com search "hyperref options"
%--> 
%--> http://www.ai.mit.edu/lab/sysadmin/latex/documentation/latex/hyperref/manual.pdf
%--> http://www.chemie.unibas.ch/~vogtp/LaTeX2PDFLaTeX.pdf 
%--> http://www.uni-giessen.de/partosch/eurotex99/ oberdiek/print/sli4a4col.pdf
%--> http://me.in-berlin.de/~miwie/tex-refs/html/latex-packages.html
%-->
\usepackage[ pdftex, plainpages = false, pdfpagelabels, 
             pdfpagelayout = useoutlines,
             bookmarks,
             bookmarksopen = true,
             bookmarksnumbered = true,
             breaklinks = true,
             linktocpage,
             pagebackref,
             colorlinks = false,  % was true
             linkcolor = blue,
             urlcolor  = blue,
             citecolor = red,
             anchorcolor = green,
             hyperindex = true,
             hyperfigures
             ]{hyperref} 

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png, .jpg, .jpeg, .pdf} %GIF doesn't work
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\graphicspath{{0_frontmatter/figures/}}



%:-------------------------- page layout -----------------------

%S5 settings (default)

\geometry{paperheight=242mm,paperwidth=165mm}
\geometry{left=22.5mm,right=22.5mm}
\geometry{top=22.5mm,bottom=22.5mm}


%Make al headlines non-fat
\def\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{-3.5ex plus -1ex minus 
    -.2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}{\Large}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}{-3.25ex plus -1ex minus 
   -.2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}{\large}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{-3.25ex plus
-1ex minus -.2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}{\normalsize}}



%:-------------------------- page layout -----------------------

% FRONTMATTER
% No page numbering until chapter 1

\newcommand{\frontmatterSU}{
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
}


% MAINMATTER
\newcommand{\mainmatterSU}{

\begingroup
\cleardoublepage
\edef\x{\endgroup
\noexpand\mainmatter
\noexpand\setcounter{page}{\the\value{page}}%
}%
\x

\cleardoublepage

\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont\thepage}}
}   % re-define plain page

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}


% BACKMATTER
\newcommand{\backmatterSU}{

\backmatter
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
%
\pagestyle{empty}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
}

% DECLARATIONS
% These macros are used to declare arguments needed for the
% construction of the title page and other preamble.

% Subtitle
\def\subtitle#1{\gdef\@subtitle{#1}}
% Defining the crest
\def\crest#1{\gdef\@crest{#1}}

% These macros define an environment for front matter that is always 
% single column even in a double-column document.

\newenvironment{alwayssingle}{%
       \@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
       \else\newpage\fi}
       {\if@restonecol\twocolumn\else\newpage\fi}

%Halftitlepage
%\newcommand{\halftitlepage}%
%{
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%   \noindent
%    {\large \@title~-- \@subtitle\\}\\
%    \noindent
%    {\Large\@author}
%\cleardoublepage
%}

\crest{\includegraphics[width=25mm]{SU-Logga}}

%define title page layout
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\relax}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
{\large \vspace*{0mm} \hspace*{90mm} {{\@crest} \par} } %Move the logo
    { \huge \vspace*{30mm}{\noindent}{\@title} \par \vspace*{4mm}}
    {\LARGE {\noindent}{\@subtitle} \par \vspace*{8mm}}
    {{\Large {\noindent}\@author} \par}
  \null\vfill
}

%:-------------------------- front matter layout -----------------------
```

Code for **thesis.bib**:

```
@article{baumeister:need,
   author = {Baumeister, R. F. and Leary, M. R.},
   title = {The need to belong: Desire for interpersonal attachments as a fundamental human motivation.},
   journal = {Psychological Bulletin},
   volume = {117},
   number = {3},
   pages = {497-529},
   year = {1995},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

Code for including citations in text:

```
\cite{baumeister:need}
```

Comment: `[options]` is not intended to be used as a literal string, it means to use whatever options you want at that point, for example the line you have commented out `\usepackage[sort,compress]{natbib}` which would use the sort and compress _options_

Comment: `\include{Latex/Macros/MacroFile1}` should be `\input` (or better give the file a `.sty` extension and use `\usepackage{MacroFile1}` you should not use `\include` in the preamble.

Comment: not strictly an error but the class file loads graphicx twice and the preamble loads it a third time (latex checks for this and only loads it once but..)

Comment: To elaborate on what David said, put `\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}` and remove the line `\setcitestyle{square,numbers}`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Please write an answer

Comment: @egreg May be David deserved an answer for this. However I have added an answer.   Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
\usepackage[options]{natbib}
```

says that `options` is the literal name of an option for `natbib` package. As this is not defined to be an option in `natbib`, an error is thrown. In fact the string `options` means the possible options like `square`, `numbers` etc.

Hence if you want to pass options to the `natbib` package while loading itself, use

```
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
```

then you won't need to use

```
% Change how references are included (see the natbib package).
\setcitestyle{square,numbers}
```

On the other hand, you may also use

```
\usepackage{natbib}     %% note the absence of options
% Change how references are included (see the natbib package).
\setcitestyle{square,numbers}
```